# Check if elem is hyperlink on Google results page on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to write an event listener in a Chrome extension that changes the style of the link when the user mouses over it.

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
     console.log(e.target.tagName);
});
```

I'm not sure if this is a problem that is isolated to the Google results page, but many of the links on the page don't print "A" for the tagName when hovered over (e.g. the search results are "H3"). On inspecting the page, it looks like "H3" is a child of "A," but I'd really just like to check whether *this element is `<a>` itself or contained in `<a>`*, so it works for all links on the page.

Is there any way to do this besides having to look up all the parents up the entire tree to see if any of them are `<a>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
aTags = document.querySelectorAll('a');
aTags.forEach(a => a.onmouseover => a.style.color = 'green');
```

This will achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should query the page for all `<a>` elements, and then bind to their `onmouseover` event.

It should look something like this:

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var a;
for(var i = 0;i < links.length;i++){
  a = links[i];
  console.log(a);
  // now you can just:
  // a.addEventListener(....);
}
```